# Regex for decimal value and optional string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a Regex to validate a rating (1-10) + optional text.
Rating is a decimal, with 1 point, which can use both dot or comma separator.
Followed by an optional space + string.

Valid

- 7
- 7,5
- 7.5
- 7,5 This is my string
- 7.5 Hello

Invalid

- 7,75
- 11
- 7This is my string
- 7.This is my string
- 10.5 string

I've got this for getting the decimal values, but I'm not sure how to get the optional text behind it.

```
^(10|\d)([\.\,]\d{1,1})?$
```

Comment: Maybe [`^(?:10|\d)(?:[.,]\d)?(?:\s+.*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/XSty0I/1) will work as expected. But here, a space is required after the number.

Comment: If the space may be missing and you may have input like `7This is my string`, try [`^(?:10|\d)(?:[.,]\d)?(?:[^\d,.].*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/XSty0I/2). However, `7.This is my string` will not get validated then.

Comment: Are `0.5` and `10.3` allowed? You said you want to match `1-10` but your regex matches `0` and `0.5` and `10.3`

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest C#

Comment: @Toto good catch, thanks! So far for my regex skills.

Comment: Is `9.0` also a valid value or does the decimal part need to be `>0`?

Comment: @silel that would be valid.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew besides the 0,5 inputs mentioned by Toto, this seems to work fine. Thanks

Comment: Could you please clarify? Check [this one](https://regex101.com/r/XSty0I/3), `^(?:10|[1-9](?:[.,]\d)?)(?:[^\d,.].*)?$`. Should `7. String here` be valid? If `10.5 string` is valid, use [`^(?:10|[1-9])(?:[.,]\d)?(?:[^\d,.].*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/XSty0I/4).

Comment: Or did `^(?:10|[1-9])(?:[.,]\d)?(?:\s+.*)?$` work for you? Sorry, I got lost in your requirements. Is the space optional after the number? You wrote *Followed by an **optional** space + string*, but later you say *7This is my string* is invalid.

Comment: The 2nd, upvoted comment worked fine. I'll try to test your posted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by your examples, the space after the initial number is not optional. Thus, the pattern you may use is

```
^(?:10|[1-9](?:[.,][0-9])?)(?:\s.*)?$
```

or - since a partial match with `Regex.IsMatch` is enough to validate the string - replace `(?:\s.*)?$` with a negative lookahead `(?!\S)` that will require a whitespace or end of string after the number:

```
^(?:10|[1-9](?:[.,][0-9])?)(?!\S)
                           ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NRn3CY/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:10|[1-9](?:[.,][0-9])?)` - either `10` or a digit from `1` to `9` followed with an optional sequence of a `,` or `.` and any single digit and then...
- `(?:\s.*)?$` - an optional sequence of any whitespace followed with any chars up to the end of string - OR -
- `(?!\S)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is no non-whitespace char immediately to the right of the current position.

[C# test](http://ideone.com/tirWmv):

```
var strs = new List<string> { "7","7,5","7.5","7,5 This is my string","7.5 Hello","7,75","11","7This is my string","7.This is my string","10.5 string"};
var pattern = @"^(?:10|[1-9](?:[.,][0-9])?)(?:\s.*)?$";
foreach (var s in strs)
    if (Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern))
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is correct.", s);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is invalid.", s);
```

Output:

```
7 is correct.
7,5 is correct.
7.5 is correct.
7,5 This is my string is correct.
7.5 Hello is correct.
7,75 is invalid.
11 is invalid.
7This is my string is invalid.
7.This is my string is invalid.
10.5 string is invalid.
```

Comment: Please drop a comment here if the regex behavior is still not as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Works great

Comment: I think the last part `(?:\s.*)?$` could also be written `(?:\s|$)`

Comment: @silel: Or even `(?!\S)`. Yes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew nice one, I wonder what the implication, performance wise, are... I suppose it mostly depends on the regex engine.

Comment: @silel: Well, I came up with `(?:\s.*)?$` because I started out matching the whole string. You are right, we do not need a whole string check here. The lookahead will be enough. I will add it as an alternative solution.